# Drone PCB - SMD part identification

Tags: identification, surface-mount

Currently I try to reverse engineer a (quite old) drone from Parrot called 'Mambo'. Here you can find some information: https://wiki.paparazziuav.org/wiki/Ap.parrot_minidrone

Currently I have identified some obvious SMD parts (red boxes). Others are still unknown (blue boxes A-F). A mystery is part C which could be a magnetic field sensor (AKM8963)(?) but according specs and firmware there should be no magnetic field sensor. Also the NAND (reported as a FIDELIX FMND1G08U3V) is not visible, but maybe installed under the camera module.

Any hints ?

[image: Top view]
[image: Bottom view]

Comment: what is your specific, answerable question?

Comment: What parts are A-F ?